# Presenting full screen modal views from a UISplitView?

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

Just looking for some advice. What is the best way to present a full screen modal view controller from a UISplitViewController (set as the root) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference presenting a modal view controller from a `UISplitViewController` that from any other `UIViewController`.

You simply call `- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated`.

Comment: Thanks - for some reason I thought the presented view would only take up space in the right or left hand part of the UISplitView.

Comment: @Ohnomycoco I didn't even consider that behavior possible. :)

Comment: Np - I've invented a problem that doesn't even exist :0

Comment: Actually I was kinda right...if you present from the right hand view controller it only fills the right hand panel :/

Comment: You need to present it from the Split view itself like you asked in your question, not the right or left end of the split vie

Comment: If you're in portrait mode, and the Master-view is visible, this modal view will only cover the detail part of the view, not both halves of the split view controller.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you know how to make a full screen controller?
2. Do you know how to present a modal view controller?
3. Are you having any problem combining the two?

Try it and if you have a specific problem ask about that.